# How do I get my simple neural network to output values closer to the labels?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm pretty new to reinforcement learning and deep Q learning. I'm trying to learn by making a tic tac toe DQN as a starter project. I have some experience with Q learning, so made a Q table and am trying to get simple NN to model the Q table.

However, the NN is not converging onto the Q table (with whatever parameters I try).

The data and code are here: https://github.com/smpurkis/pytorch_playground/tree/master/tic_tac_toe

I thought I was going crazy, so decided to train for 25 epochs on a single input and output. As the label and output should be almost exactly the same then.

I found the same problem. So am completely lost as to why the network isn't converging exactly.

Any thought, or help would be greatly appreciated!

Code is below.

```
import warnings
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


class TicTacToeModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, board_size=3, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.learning_rate = 0.001

        # basic network, should be enough to approximate Q-table. Have tried much more complex models, same result
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(board_size**2, board_size**2)
        # self.hidden_layer = nn.Linear(board_size**2, board_size**2)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(board_size**2, board_size**2)

    def forward(self, t):
        # rely to add non-linearity
        t = F.tanh(self.input_layer(t))
        # t = F.tanh(self.hidden_layer(t))
        t = self.output_layer(t)
        return t

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        # standard loss for regression
        loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
        loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)

        return {"loss": loss}

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        return [optimizer]

    def train_dataloader(self):
        self.static_q_table = StaticQTable()
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=self.static_q_table, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
        return train_dataloader


class StaticQTable(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = np.load("10000_games.npy", allow_pickle=True)
        self.q = self.q[np.random.randint(self.q.shape[0], size=1), :]
        self.db = pd.DataFrame(self.q, columns=["state", "q_values"])

    def __len__(self):
        return self.q.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        state, q_values = torch.Tensor(self.q[index][0]), torch.Tensor(self.q[index][1])

        if not int(torch.max(torch.abs(q_values))) == 0:
            q_values = torch.div(q_values, torch.max(torch.abs(q_values)))

        return [state, q_values]

    def get_q_values(self, state):
        return self.db.loc[self.db["state"] == state, "q_values"].values[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # example state, -1 = O, 1 = X
    # state = torch.Tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 0., 1.])

    net = TicTacToeModel()
    trainer = pl.Trainer(min_epochs=1, max_epochs=25, gpus=1)
    trainer.fit(net)
    torch.save(net.state_dict(), "static_model.pth")
    # net.load_state_dict(torch.load("static_model.pth"))

    net.eval()
    state = torch.Tensor(net.static_q_table.q[0][0])
    q_values = torch.Tensor(net.static_q_table.q[0][1])
    if not int(torch.max(torch.abs(q_values))) == 0:
        q_values = torch.div(q_values, torch.max(torch.abs(q_values)))
    print(state, q_values)
    output = net(state)
    print(output)
    # output I got, in my last try
    # board state: tensor([ 0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0., -1., -1.,  1.]) 
    # labels: tensor([1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.8100, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000])
    # NN output: tensor([ 0.1497, -0.0335,  0.0308, -0.1341,  0.0103,  0.0310, -0.1358, -0.0607, -0.0380], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Comment: The code is not running for me, since I don't have a gpu, but the line ```y_hat = self(x)``` looks weird. Do you mean ```y_hat  = self.x```?

Comment: The `self(x)` is short hand for `self.forward(x)`. In this case feeds the board state through the network. 
You should be able to run it on cpu if you set the `gpus=0` in the line `trainer = pl.Trainer(min_epochs=1, max_epochs=25, gpus=1)`